# Trouble creating SQL Server 2012 trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I'm quite new at SQL Server 2012, and I'm having a strange problem.

I've developed an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on a table in my database. I created the trigger in our development environment which is an express edition of SQL Server 2012, no problem.

Now I have to create the same trigger in our production environment which is SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition, and the creation script never stops executing, and the trigger is not created.

Any ideas on what I need to do to create the trigger?

The script :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter TRIGGER [dbo].[til_aks_ved_betaling] 
   ON [dbo].[betalingsOplysningerbo] 
   AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @snr          uniqueidentifier
    declare @@status      varchar(1024)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    select 
        @snr = indmeldelse_snr 
    from 
        inserted

    if UPDATE(betalingsDato)        
    begin          
         set @@status = 'Kalder med snr = ' + convert(varchar(38), @snr)     

         exec xp_logevent 60000,  @@status , informational                
         exec overfoer_betalingsdato @snr
    end
 END
```

Comment: it will fail if more than one row is updated. What is the primary key column in your table?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @snr = indmeldelse_snr from inserted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: `betalingsOplysningerbo` might be locked.

Comment: could the major flaw, that i didn't take into account that i won't fire once per row, explain why i can't create the trigger on the table in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

2 things here, common for new people, an UPDATE is a DELETE and an INSERT so make sure you have both before you assume it is an update. Second, these special tables will return all the rows affect by a single sql call. For example, `Update Table SET This = 'That'` will update every record in the table leaving INSERTED with MANY records.

Comment: apart from the "bad" trigger design i've made, the problem, not beeing able to create the trigger, seems to be caused by an orphaned process, that keeps a lock on the table. i'll try to kill the process and recreate the trigger

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[til_aks_ved_betaling] 
ON  [dbo].[betalingsOplysningerbo] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @snr          VARCHAR(1000);
        declare @status      varchar(1024);    


   DECLARE @Temp TABLE (indmeldelse_snr uniqueidentifier , [Status]  varchar(1024))

   INSERT INTO @Temp (indmeldelse_snr  , [Status])
   SELECT i.indmeldelse_snr , i.[Status]
   FROM inserted i INNER JOIN deleted d 
   ON i.Snr = d.Snr AND i.betalingsDato <> d.betalingsDato


WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Temp)
  BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @snr = 'Kalder med snr = ' + convert(varchar(38),indmeldelse_snr )
                         ,@status = [Status]
        FROM @Temp 

        exec xp_logevent 60000,  @status , informational                
        exec overfoer_betalingsdato @snr

        DELETE FROM @Temp WHERE indmeldelse_snr = @snr

    END 

 END
```